# Why the jQuery script works only for the first row in a table

Tags: jquery

Html Code:

```
<?php if($accountsAwaitingRow_cnt != 0): ?>
                                    <?php foreach($accountsawaitingarray as $datum): ?>
                        <tr data-id="<?php echo $datum['ID']; ?>" id="rowID" href="#">
                          <td id="userID"><?php echo $datum['ID']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($datum['Account']); ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $datum['SubmitDate']; ?></td>
                          <td><span class="label label-warning">Pending</span></td>
                          <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($datum['Email']); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <span style="color:red">*</span>There are no accounts awaiting approval, check back later.
                            <?php endif; ?>
```

Script:

```
    $("#rowID").click(function(){
    var User = $("#userID");
    var Box = $("#userBox");

    Box.show();
 $("#userBox").animate({
     maxHeight: '+=1000px'
 }, 1000);

 $("html, body").animate({
     scrollTop: $(document).height()
 }, 1000);

    $("#thisHR").show();
 $("#thisHR").animate({
    maxWidth: '+=1000px'
 }, 1000);

}
);
```

What I want to acomplish is, when an administrator clicks on a row in a table there will be a box that will appear and expand with the informations of the user, it works only with the first row and I do not understand why.

Comment: You can't re-use `id` values in HTML.  It's supposed to uniquely *identify* the element.  The jQuery selector is just finding the first matching `id`, because by definition there shouldn't be any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("#rowID").click(); sets the listener on the element with ID of "rowID". ID's are supposed to be unique so it applies the listener only to the first element with that ID. If you want to set the listener on all elements you should be using classes. e.g. class="clickable-row"

Comment: Oh, thank you, didn't notice the mistake, also thanks to @David too